# Make my jQuery Ajax script use CORS

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, blackberry-webworks, cors

I built an application which reads data via AJAX from an external website. It works fine but I found out in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10881561/773263) that if I want to package it for BlackBerry 7, with Webworks or Phonegap, I may need to use something called [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

How can I convert my following script to do the same thing except using 'CORS'?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#page_all").live('pagebeforecreate', function() {
        $.get('http://mysite.com/mobile/data/data_all.php',function(data){
            $('.content').empty();
            $(data).find('market').each(function(){
                var $market = $(this);
                var html = '<div class="data">';                      
                html += '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b"><h3>' + $market.attr('date') + '</h3>';
                html += '</div>';
                $('#result').append(html).trigger( "create" );
                $('#result .loading').remove();
            });                        
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what's your package engine? PhoneGap? Titanium?

Comment: Have used both WebWorks & PhoneGap, results for each package engine are at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10799838/773263

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are probably hitting the domain (ontariosheep.org) from other domain name, and that brings the cross-domain into the poll.

CORS is just a way to solve this, and it has to be your server that hosts `data_all.php` that needs to be set to also have in the response header the property:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

or, you can use the other common method called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

using JSONP method, you call should look like:

```
var url = "http://ontariosheep.org/mobile/data/data_all.php";
$.get(url + "?callback=?", function(data) {
    // your method body     
});
```

Comment: I've already added <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?> to data_all.php

Comment: can you use Fiddler or other sniffer to see that the header is passed correctly? did you use JSONP just to try out? **P.S.** you should pass a JSON string instead of XML data to successfully work, I had problems with encoding when passing XML data instead of JSON once.

Comment: I've downloaded Fiddler but not exactly sure how to check. The code works in most situations its only when I convert it into a BlackBerry App that it fails to work.

Comment: this is how you use Fiddler to see the headers: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FUMC7.png - Seams ok though.

Comment: It could also be necessary to allow specific headers and/or credentials like so (in PHP): `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: SOAPAction,SOAPServer,Content-Type,Authorization,Method"); header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");`

Answer (score -2):

You could turn on CORS in jquery specifically with

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

Also, make sure to configure your widget config correctly (config.xml) and add

```
<access uri="*" />
```

or at least

```
<access uri="ontariosheep.com" />
```

Comment: `$.support.cors` __checks__ for support; it does __not__ _enable_ it.