# AJAX only able to connect locally, Not using JSON on server side

Tags: javascript, ajax

The ajax call can is able to do it on locally, but when I change it to let say, my own IP or the server(another machine) IP address then it will is not able to communicate with the server itself?

How can I resolve this? I'm not using JSON on the server so can I still change the dataType to json and use it to connect[tried bu there is error:0 and error:200 for jsonp].

```
<script>
$(function() {  
  $(".button").on("click",(function() {  
      var cli=$("input#clien").val();
      var use=$("input#username").val();
      var dataString="Clien="+cli+"&UserName="+use;
      $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({  
              type: "POST",  
              url: "http://localhost:8080/services/web?wsdl/Authen",
```

if I change (to another host PC IP address) it to

```
url: "http://192.168.1.23:8080/services/web?wsdl/Authen",
```

then it will has no response from server.

```
              data: dataString,
              dataType:'html',
```

But if i change the  dataType to json, the server is able to receive and generate something but no response is able to received on the client side.

```
              cache: false,
              success: function(data, status, response) {
                alert(response);
            },
              error: function(request,status,response){
                    alert("Error: "+request.status+","+request.statusText);  
              }
            }); 
                return false;   
      }));  
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: Is port 8080 unblocked on your firewall?

Comment: Use relative path like "services/web?wsdl/Authen" not full path.

Comment: yes port 8080 is unblocked on my firewall as well as my host firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative URI,

for instance change:

```
url:"http://localhost:8080/services/web?wsdl/Authen"
```

to

```
url:"/services/web?wsdl/Authen"
```

in your ajax request

Comment: but I need to connect to another host with a different IP? I don't need to connect to my localhost..

Comment: In that case, look into CORS, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881868/make-my-jquery-ajax-script-use-cors

Comment: I look that too, but Im not using PHP? my host uses axis2 for webservices.